# Is my for loop not looping though all data?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am trying to populate database using for loop. While submitting the form I am getting the following data:

```
"name" => "This is a product title"
  "slug" => "this-is-a-product-title"
  "category_id" => "1"
  "brand_id" => "1"
  "description" => "<p>This is a product description</p>"
  "video" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY1F_Y0GniQ"
  "imageColor" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "image" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "["http://ecom.local/uploads/product-1.jpg","http://ecom.local/uploads/product-2.jpg"]"
    1 => "["http://ecom.local/uploads/product-4.jpg","http://ecom.local/uploads/product-3.jpg"]"
  ]
  "color" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "size" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "11"
    1 => "9"
  ]
  "stock" => "2"
  "price" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "4000"
    1 => "3000"
  ]
  "discount" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "0"
    1 => "0"
  ]
  "status" => "active"
```

In order to populate data I have written the following code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $rules = $this->product->getRules();
    $request->validate($rules);
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['name'] = $request->name;
    $data['slug'] = $request->slug;
    $data['category_id'] = $request->category_id;
    $data['brand_id'] = $request->brand_id;
    $data['video'] = $request->video;
    $data['status'] = $request->status; 
    $this->product->fill($data);
    $status = $this->product->save();
    $product_id = $this->product->id;
    if($status){
        if(!empty($request->image)){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($request->image);){
                    $images = $request->image[$i];
                    $images = str_replace('"', '', $images);
                    $images = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$images);
                    $images = explode(',', $images);
                for($j = 0; $j < count($images[$i]);){
                    $image_data['product_id'] = $product_id;
                    $image_data['color_id'] = $request->imageColor[$i];
                    $image_data['image'] = $images[$j];
                    $this->product_image->fill($image_data);
                    $this->product_image->save();
                    $j++;
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
        if(!empty($request->size)){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($request->size); $i++){
                $size_data['product_id'] = $product_id;
                $size_data['size_id'] = $request->size[$i];
                $this->product_size->fill($size_data);
                $this->product_size->save();
            }
        }
        $request->session()->flash('success','Product created successfully.');
    } else {
        $request->session()->flash('error','Problem while adding product.');
    }
    return redirect()->route('products.index');
}
```

But, every time I insert a product I only get single row being populated in product_images and product_sizes table. Is my for loop not working or there is a bug in my code?
For now I am getting this result with my code:
[image]
My expected answer would look like the following in product images tabel
[image]

Comment: So your image data is an array, consisting of two entries - that in turn each contain _two_ image URLs, but somehow in an array-as-string format? (Why?)

Comment: Maybe, you are trying to say why am I getting data in array-as-string format. If it is, I am using responsive filemanager and while selecting multiple images with file manager, we get data like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new Images like this example below:

```
[...]
$product_image = new Image;
$image_data['product_id'] = $product_id;
$image_data['color_id'] = $request->imageColor[$i];
$image_data['image'] = $images[$j];
$product_image->fill($image_data);
$product_image->product_id = $this->id;
$product_image->save();
[...]
```

Otherwise it will only create a single one.

I think the for loop is wrong too:

```
for($j = 0; $j < count($images[$i]);){
```

change it into:

```
for($j = 0; $j < count($images);){
```

Comment: Hello. I have my object defined in the beginning.

Comment: And, I don't think that is the problem because the above code is inserting data to respective tables. The problem is all the data are not being populated.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your expected result and the actual result?

Comment: I have added a diagram about my expected answer.

Comment: Your code overrides the entry four times. So i still believe that you have to initialize new Images like the code above. Have you tried it?

Comment: Even though it didn't felt like the object issue, but, it was actually the object and loop also worked as you have advice in the answer.